# Graphviz edges with ortho lines not aligning with ports

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create a graphviz block diagram with bidirectional arrows. I have used this graphviz code created from python graphviz package. After exploring the edge options, I liked ortho edges but when I code that, the edges are not getting connected to ports properly and the labels are not at all aligned to the edges. What can I do to fix this. Thanks a lot in advance :D

```
digraph {
    graph [nodesep=.3 rankdir=LR ranksep=2 splines=ortho]
    node [shape=record]
    Node1 [label="{{Node1}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node2 [label="{<p0>B|{Node2}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node3 [label="{<p0>B|{Node3}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node4 [label="{<p0>B|{Node4}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node5 [label="{<p0>B|{Node5}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node6 [label="{<p0>B|{Node6}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node7 [label="{<p0>B|{Node7}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node8 [label="{<p0>B|{Node8}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node9 [label="{<p0>B|{Node9}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node10 [label="{<p0>B|{Node10}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node1:<f0> -> Node2:<p0>
    Node1:<f1> -> Node3:<p0>
    Node1:<f2> -> Node4:<p0>
    Node2:<f0> -> Node5:<p0>
    Node2:<f1> -> Node6:<p0>
    Node2:<f2> -> Node7:<p0>
    Node2:<p0> -> Node1:<f0>
    Node3:<f0> -> Node8:<p0>
    Node3:<f1> -> Node9:<p0>
    Node3:<f2> -> Node10:<p0>
    Node3:<p0> -> Node1:<f1>
    Node4:<p0> -> Node1:<f2>
    Node5:<p0> -> Node2:<f0>
    Node6:<p0> -> Node2:<f1>
    Node7:<p0> -> Node2:<f2>
    Node8:<p0> -> Node3:<f0>
    Node9:<p0> -> Node3:<f1>
    Node10:<p0> -> Node3:<f2>
}
```

This is the graphviz code that python backend generated.

[image: graphviz output ortho]

This is what generated when using lines. It represents correctly but I would like to have ortho edges rather than line

[image: graphviz output lines]

Answer (score 2):

For `splines=ortho` you should not use the label specifiers for the edges, so instead of `Node1:<f0> -> Node2:<p0>` you can just use `Node1 -> Node2`.

```
digraph {
    graph [nodesep=.3 rankdir=LR ranksep=2 splines=ortho]
    node [shape=record]
    Node1 [label="{{Node1}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node2 [label="{<p0>B|{Node2}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node3 [label="{<p0>B|{Node3}|{<f0>A|<f1>A|<f2>A}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node4 [label="{<p0>B|{Node4}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node5 [label="{<p0>B|{Node5}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node6 [label="{<p0>B|{Node6}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node7 [label="{<p0>B|{Node7}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node8 [label="{<p0>B|{Node8}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node9 [label="{<p0>B|{Node9}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node10 [label="{<p0>B|{Node10}}" fontsize=25 width=3]
    Node1 -> Node2
    Node1 -> Node3
    Node1 -> Node4
    Node2 -> Node5
    Node2 -> Node6
    Node2 -> Node7
    Node2 -> Node1
    Node3 -> Node8
    Node3 -> Node9
    Node3 -> Node10
    Node3 -> Node1
    Node4 -> Node1
    Node5 -> Node2
    Node6 -> Node2
    Node7 -> Node2
    Node8 -> Node3
    Node9 -> Node3
    Node10 -> Node3
}
```

Result:

[image]